# Decomposition of tensor field on hypersurface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensor, lorentzian-geometry

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold, which is globally of the form $\mathcal{M}\cong I\times\Sigma$, where $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ ("time") and $\Sigma$ ("space") is some $3$-dimensional hypersurface. Let us further choose a coordinate chart $U=(t,x^{i})$ such that the metric takes the form
$$g\vert_{U}=-\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t+h_{t}$$
where $h_{t}$ is a Riemannian metric on $\Sigma$ for each $t$ (this is always possible and usually called (Gaussian) normal coordinates). The coordinate $t$ is interpreted as "time", whereas the coordinates $(x^{i})$ of the Riemannian manifold $(\Sigma,h)$ as space.

Now, let $T$ be an arbitrary symmetric $2$-tensor field on $\mathcal{M}$. Then, in the local coordinate system introduced above, we can decompose

$$T_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}=T_{00}\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}t+2T_{i0}\mathrm{d}t\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{i}+T_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^{i}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{j}.$$

This essentially provides a decomposition of the form (in the sense of $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$-module isomorphisms)

$$\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\mathcal{M}^{\otimes_{s}2})\cong C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)\oplus\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2})$$

where $T_{00}$ is interpreted as a function in $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$, $T_{i0}$ of beeing the components in coordinates of an element in $\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ and similarely for $T_{ij}$.

Now, is it possible to establish isomorphisms

$$C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\cong C^{\infty}(I,C^{\infty}(\Sigma))$$
$$\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)\cong C^{\infty}(I,\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma))$$
$$\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2})\cong C^{\infty}(I,\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2}))$$

i.e. to interpret $T_{00}$, $T_{i0}$ and $T_{ij}$ as a "smooth time-dependent functions, co-vector and tensor fields", respectively? What I mean with "smooth" in the notation above is the following: If $X:I\to\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ is a map, for example, then $X_{p}(t)\in T_{p}^{\ast}\Sigma$ for all $p\in\mathcal{M}$, $t\in I$, and hence, it makes sense to define the derivative with respect to $t$ in the usual way, i.e.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}X_{p}(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{X_{p}(t+h)-X_{p}(t)}{h}$$

where we choose an arbitrary norm on $T_{p}^{\ast}\Sigma$, for example, the one induced by the metric $g$ (the choice does not matter, since on finite-dimensional spaces they are all equivalent). Similarely, the spaces are defined for the other two cases.

(Previously posted on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620996/decomposition-of-tensor-field-on-hypersurface))

Comment: Yes. This is always implicitly assumed. You can look for example at semigroup formulation for parabolic or hyperbolic PDE's.

Comment: @RomainGicquaud thanks for the comment! Could you be more precise what you mean by "implicitely assumed"? Like, are the isos above true in general or just under some assumptions? Also do you have some literature on parabolic/hyperbolic pdes mentioning these type of splittings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are not isomorphic. Consider the function $$X(t,x,y,z)=\begin{cases}xt\frac{x^2-t^2}{x^2+t^2},&\text{ if $(x,t)\ne(0,0)$},\\ 0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ This is not a smooth function on $M=\mathbb{R}^{1+3}=I\times \Sigma$, $I=\mathbb{R}$, $\Sigma=\mathbb{R}^3$, since $\partial_{xt}X\ne \partial_{tx} X$ at the origin. If I understand your definition of smoothness correctly, this is a smooth function in $C^{\infty}(I,C^{\infty}(\Sigma))$, $X_p(t)=X(t,p)$, $p=(x,y,z)$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the great example. Do you have an argument to see that it is at least true that $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\subset C^{\infty}(I,C^{\infty}(\Sigma))$ (your example shows that $\supset$ cannot be true in general). In the end, I am mainly interested in the following question: If I decompose a tensor field as in my question, is it possible to interpret the components as "smooth time-depending objects".

Comment: @B.Hueber: the inclusion $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\subset C^{\infty}(I,C^{\infty}(\Sigma))$ follows first from the fact that a smooth function of several variables is smooth in each of those variables when the others are fixed, hence your definition of smooth applies to show that each element of the LHS gives one of the right, and then that the map is injective, since vanishing of derivatives can be checked in the $t$ variable first and then then other variables, by commutativity of partial derivatives.